# Error "A server with the specified host-name could not be found"

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

Here is the scenario : I am using silent push notification in my application , when the app is in background and a notification is received the delegate method is called which is fine. But the issue is that I have an API call in the `didreceivepushnotification` and the response is only received only when I move the app to the foreground, the above stated error is received in the API call response.

The whole scenario works fine when the app is in foreground.

Comment: Show us your code. Did you hard code the API call address?

Comment: You will need call `beginBackgroundTask` before you start an asynchronous network operation in the background in order to prevent your app from being suspended when the app,delegate method returns

Comment: Thanks! @Paulw11 this solution is work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add your request as a background task. It won’t fire as expected unless you'll do it.